Add tooltip/hint hover header of panel in Belnder Addon
In Blender addon api, How to add tooltip/hint when hover over header(or label) of sub panel under layout
class MyPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    ...
    header, panel = self.layout.panel(idname = "rigs_enabled", default_closed = True)
    header.label(text="Enable additional choices")
    if panel:
        ...


according to the documentation it should be just a matter of using bl_description but it doesn't seem to show any tooltip nor error on my side.

But at the same time, looking at tooltips guidelines, i suspect you can do enough with the panel's header label and a tooltip would probably be redundant.

I want to add tooltip to this section (subpanel)
